# Is it possible to use xpath with nested loops?

Tags: c#, loops, xpath, nested, html-agility-pack

So i am trying to parse some html with xpath.Here is how my page looks like

```
<area id="a_0_0" alt="asd">
<area id="a_0_1" alt="asd">
<area id="a_1_0" alt="asd">
<area id="a_1_1" alt="asd">
```

so is it possible to parse it with xpath ? or do i need to use something else ? I am a bit new to xpath here is what i've tried

```
doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//area[@id='a_0_0']").Attributes["alt"].Value;//this is works 

doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//area[@id='a_0_[position() >=0 and position() <=1]']").Attributes["alt"].Value
doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//area[@id='a_[position() >=0 and position() <=1]']_[position() >=0 and position() <=1]']").Attributes["alt"].Value
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the simple solution.

```
var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//area[contains('a_0_0,a_0_1,a_1_0,a_1_1',id)]")
foreach (var node in nodes)
{
    // node.Attributes["alt"].Value
}
```

Also you can use below to get all area nodes which have alt attribute.

```
var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//area[@alt]");
```

To get all the area nodes that starts with `a_` use the below.

```
var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//area[starts-with(@id,'a_')][@alt]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can parse your xml to XDocument and benefit from linq.

```
XDocument.Parse(xmlstring)
```